# SQL Server values from Detail table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables ItemMaster and ItemDetail, I am creating a report to display columns from both tables.

I want to display First 3 columns from "ItemMaster" table and then Max(FinishDate) and Max(Amount) from "ItemDetail" table.

I tried to generate results as below written query but not working.

Please help 
Thanks

```
SELECT  IM.ItemCode,
        IM.Customer,
        IM.FinYear,  
        DET.FinishDate,
        DET.Amount
 FROM  ItemMaster AS IM
 INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(FinishDate) AS FinishDate, MAX(Amount) AS Amount
              FROM   ItemDetail ID
              WHERE  IM.ItemCode = ID.ItemCode) AS DET
 ON IM.ItemCode = DET.ItemCode
```

[image]

Comment: please paste expected result and actual result as ddl and not images

Comment: please take a look at this link to know more on how to improve question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the query of the derived table a little bit so as to include a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT  IM.ItemCode,
        IM.Customer,
        IM.FinYear,  
        DET.FinishDate,
        DET.Amount
 FROM  ItemMaster AS IM
 INNER JOIN ( SELECT ID.ItemCode,
                     MAX(FinishDate) AS FinishDate, MAX(Amount) AS Amount
              FROM   ItemDetail ID
              GROUP BY ID.ItemCode) AS DET
 ON IM.ItemCode = DET.ItemCode
```

Now you can do a proper `JOIN` on the `ItemCode` field.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your provided solution worked too

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  SELECT  IM.ItemCode ,
            IM.Customer ,
            IM.FinYear ,
            DET.FinishDate ,
            DET.Amount
    FROM    ItemMaster AS IM
            CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    MAX(FinishDate) AS FinishDate ,
                                    MAX(Amount) AS Amount
                          FROM      ItemDetail ID
                          WHERE     ID.ItemCode = IM.ItemCode
                        ) AS DET
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no sub-select needed, imho. Just join both tables and aggregate as you would do on a single table:

```
select im.ItemCode, im.Customer, im.FinYear,
       MAX(id.FinishDate), MAX(id.Amount)
  from ItemMaster im
  join ItemDetail id
    on im.ItemCode = id.ItemCode
  group by im.ItemCode, im.Customer, im.FinYear
```